# What is the charge of a scalar field in the context of black hole hair?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, conservation-laws

The electric charge is given by integrating the Hodge dual of the electric current

$$\int_V \star j =\int_V d \star  F =\int _{\partial V} \star F$$.

I was told that the charge of a sclar field $\phi$ is obtained integrating the gradient of $\phi$ over a surface

$$\int dS n^\mu \partial_\mu \phi$$

where $n^\mu$ is a normal vector to the surface.
But why is this last formula correct.

I guess that the scalar current is $j=d\phi$, but I'm confused because this is obtained by  the equations of motion, not gauge symmetry.

Comment: I think it's to do with there being two notions of charge conservation. One is the global symmetry of a complex scalar field $\phi\to e^{i\alpha}\phi$, $\alpha$ a real constant, which would leave the usual lagrangian invariant, and give rise to a noether charge via noethers theorem. The other is the local transformation $\phi(x)\to e^{i\alpha(x)}\phi(x)$. In order for this to be a symmetry one usually follows the minimal coupling procedure, introducing a gauge field $A_\mu$.

Comment: Then changing the ordinary derivatives to covariant ones $\partial_\mu\to D_\mu= \partial_\mu +i A_\mu$, and additionally one makes the gauge field to transform according to $A_\mu\to A_\mu -\partial_\mu\alpha$. In this case then $D_\mu \phi \to e^{i\alpha}D_\mu \phi$, and we should get a local symmetry of the new Lagrangian.

Comment: @snulty I forgot to mention that the field is real.